# jqwicket+separate javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket

I have problem to put my own Javascript in a separate file and use it from JQWicket (testing Drag & drop plugin). Here is myscript.js:

```
com.mycompany.Test = function() {
return {
    test_func: function() {
        $('#msg').text('X position = ' + ui.position.left + ', Y position = ' + ui.position.top);
    }
}
}
```

And in the java I want to call test_func:

```
DraggableOptions drop = new DraggableOptions().dragEvent(
            "com.mycompany.Test.test_func()");
```

But it does not work! I think the problem is that myscript.js is included before jquery.js and I do not know how to reorder include statements.

I'm very grateful if anyone has a working example with a separate javascript file that is called from jqwicket!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an JQBehavior instance referencing "myscript.js" to your component/page like this:

```
JQBehavior behavior = new JQBehavior();
behavior.addJsResourceUrls("myscript.js");

Component comp = .... ;
comp.add(behavior);
```